# Comments in Doxygen .dox file

Tags: comments, doxygen

I have a .dox file and want to insert some comments that will not be 
displayed in the actual documentation.

Have tried using only `//`, Horever, when I tried, all the text ir removed.

```
/// \defgroup desc_polyhedra Polyhedra
///
// If you want to prevent that a word that corresponds to a 
// documented class is replaced by a link you should put a % in 
// front of the word.
///
/// \section Polyhedron 
///
/// A polyhedron is a solid in three dimensions with flat faces, 
/// straight edges and sharp corners or vertices. 
///
/// Amongst the many examples of polyhedra, the Cuboid and 
/// Prismatoid structures will be considered in more detail. 
/// Here is a brief summary of cuboids and prismatoids.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options here:

1. Surround the text you want left alone with `\cond` ... `\endcond`
2. Have a completely separate comment section with *only* `//` - i.e. don't mix `//` in the middle of the `///` section.  What you are seeing is that the first `//` ends the doxygen comment block, so it stops coming out in the output.
3. Use HTML comment syntax within the doxygen section `/// <--! A comment is here -->`

Comment: I am using `\cond ... \endcond`